# algorithm to find the rough time in advance of the query

Tags: database, oracle

Does anyone `knows or think` of a script or `tool`,which will tell the `rough estimate` of *"How long the query will take to execute"* ,Like when we copy a file in windows to some external device ,it gives the roughly estimate of the time ,it will take to copy .
Can anyone think of creating any `algorithm` based on explain plan ?.
I dnt know whether this is the right forum to ask such question or not .But this question came in my mind , so i asked.

Comment: I wouldn't want it to be just like the status when windows copies files. The estimated times are always way off :)

Comment: @VishalKumar:Not like that ,just an algorithm reads explain plan and tell the rough estimated time in advance.So that i am prepared mentally that this much time it will take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TIME` column of the query plan already gives you the optimizer's estimate of the elapsed time

```
SQL> select *
  2    from table( dbms_xplan.display );

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3956160932

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |    14 |   546 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    14 |   546 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

8 rows selected.
```

Obviously, the optimizer's estimate can certainly be incorrect.  But that generally implies that the statistics on the objects are incorrect in some way.  Assuming your algorithm would be using the same statistics, it seems unlikely that your estimate would be much more accurate.

Comment: @Guarav You should look into running [DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SYSTEM_STATS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_stats.htm#i1036401).  It may help improve the TIME estimate.  But if you're not using 11.2.0.3 you have to watch out for bugs like 9842771, where some of the numbers are set incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has v$session_longops view that will estimate completion time for some queries. Longops contains info for: Table scan; Index Fast Full Scan; Hash join; Sort/Merge; Sort Output; Rollback; Gather Table's Index Statistics. [but not nested loops]

For example, you can query as follows:

```
select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:MI:SS') date_measured
, sql_id
, elapsed
, remaining 
, ROUND(sofar/totalwork*100, 2) progress_pct
, username
, sql_text
, inst_id, sid, serial#
, logon_time
, OSUSER
, terminal
, machine
, program
, last_call_et
from
(
SELECT s.inst_id
       ,s.sid
       ,s.serial#
       ,s.username
       ,s.OSUSER
       ,s.machine
       ,s.sql_id
       ,TRUNC(sl.elapsed_seconds/60) || ':' || MOD(sl.elapsed_seconds,60) elapsed
       ,TRUNC(sl.time_remaining/60) || ':' || MOD(sl.time_remaining,60) remaining
       , sl.sofar
       , sl.totalwork
       ,s.logon_time
       ,s.terminal
       ,s.program
       ,s.last_call_et
       ,sa.sql_text
FROM   gv$session s
       ,gv$session_longops sl
       ,gv$sqlarea sa
WHERE  s.inst_id = sl.inst_id
  AND  s.sid     = sl.sid
  AND  s.serial# = sl.serial#
  and s.sql_id = sa.sql_id 
  and s.inst_id = sa.inst_id 
) a
where remaining not in ('0:0',':')
;
```

Again, longops does not have all queries in it, but it provides interesting information for long running queries that meet it's criteria for inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of factors that go into this.

This paper may give you some insight into what you are looking for:
ftp://ftp.research.microsoft.com/users/autoadmin/progress.pdf